# How to remove reminder saved as an EKReminder?

Tags: ios, ekevent, ekeventstore

I have saved a reminder using EKReminder,now I want to remove this reminder from EKReminder.
I have date and time of the reminder to be removed. I tried using NSPRedicate but it didn't work for me.

I am using this code:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init] ;

            EKReminder *reminder = [EKReminder
                                    reminderWithEventStore:eventStore];

            reminder.calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewReminders];

            EKAlarm *reminderDate = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:removeReminder];
            [reminder removeAlarm:reminderDate];

            NSError *error = nil;

            [eventStore removeReminder:reminder commit:YES error:&error];

            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"Reminder removed successfully");
            }
```

Where removeReminder is my date.

Please suggest me if there is problem with this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init] ;
            
           
            NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewReminders]];

            
            NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForRemindersInCalendars:calendarArray];
            
            [eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:^(NSArray *reminders)
             {
            for (EKReminder *reminder  in reminders)
            {
             //here based on reminder.title i removed the reminder.

             [eventStore removeReminder:reminder commit:YES error:nil];

            }
```